# The comprehension of a paragraph about point-ultraweak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation below (in the book "C*-algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations")

Remark 2.1.3. It follows from Sakai's predual uniqueness theorem that when checking point-ultra weak convergence of bounded nets, **it always suffices to check convergence on certain vector functionals.** That is, if $N\subset B(H)$ is any faithful normal representation and $\Omega\subset H$ is any set of vectors whose linear span is dense in $H$, then $\psi_{n} \circ\phi_{n} \rightarrow \theta$ in the point-ultraweak topology if and only if 
$$\langle \psi_{n} \circ\phi_{n} (a)v, w \rangle \rightarrow \langle\theta(a)v, w\rangle$$
for all $a\in A$ and $v, w\in \Omega$.

My question is:

**1. What does the bold words above mean?**

**2. Does the author want to describle the  the point-ultraweak topology is equivalent to point-weak topology on the bounded nets?**

**3. How to explain the $\Omega$ that the author take?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are just saying that the ultraweak topology agrees with the weak operator topology on bounded sets. So you can test convergence on functionals of the form $x\mapsto\langle x\xi,\eta\rangle$, $\xi,\eta\in H$.

And if you have a set $\Omega$ with dense span in $H$, one can check that if $\langle x_j v,w\rangle\to0$ for all $v,w\in \Omega$, then $\langle x_j\xi,\eta\rangle\to0$ for all $\xi,\eta\in H$.